# CSS How To Blur/Bleed Sides Of Image

Tags: css

I have a large image centered like this:
[image]

I want to image to bleed with a blur on the sides like this:

[image]

Is this possible?
Also, is there a particular term used to describe what I want?

I tried adding a background image and blurring that, but then I realized that just blurs everything. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: It's a 'backdrop'. You can use the [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) for this. Although I think you will need to use two  stacked images. The lower image is not only blurred, but scaled up, stretched horizontally and (probably) cut a piece from the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way to do this, but this at the very least works and doesn't seem to be messing up anything.

What I did was create a container and then stack the same image on top of each other, but set the image at the bottom to be blurred and fill the remaining gaps.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className='container'>
        {/* ORDERING MATTERS!! */}
        <img className='bleed-blur' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/packs/media/vectors/term-bg-1-666de2d9.jpg' />
        <img className='main-image' src='https://static.vecteezy.com/packs/media/vectors/term-bg-1-666de2d9.jpg' />


      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

**App.css**

```
.bleed-blur{
  /* required to stack images on top of each other */
  position: absolute;

  /* blur effect */
  filter: blur(10px);

  /* the size will be relative to the container */
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

.container{
  /* will cause other content will not be adjusted to fit into any 
     gap left by the element */
  position: relative;

  /* you may want to adjust the sizing to your liking*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh; 

  /* center images within container */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-image{
  /* required to stack images on top of each other */
  position: absolute;

  /* the size will be relative to the container */
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;

  /* you can change this if you need to, but might cuase issues. 
     Although, `scale-down` seems to work well*/
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

The desired effects (you can play around with the width and height):
[image]

[image]

---

**Edit:**
if you don't want the background image to be streched, you can change the css for `.bleed-blur` to have `object-fit: contain` so that it maintains aspect ratio but is bigger that the container but also don't cause the container to change in size.

```
.bleed-blur{
  /* required to stack images on top of each other */
  position: absolute;

  /* blur effect */
  filter: blur(10px);

  /* the size will be relative to the container */
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;

  /* you can change this if you need to, but might cuase issues. 
     Although, `scale-down` seems to work well*/
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

[image]

Comment: since you are using `position:absolute`, why not add `z-index:0` to `.bleed-blur` and `z-index:1` to `.main-image`. Then, ordering won't matter anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  background:#000;
}

.bg{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  background-image:url("https://static.vecteezy.com/packs/media/vectors/term-bg-1-666de2d9.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-item:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  filter: blur(14px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
figure{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:50%;
  transform:translate(50%);
  overflow:hidden;
  width:70%;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
 <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="bg">
      </div>   
   <figure>
        <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/packs/media/vectors/term-bg-1-666de2d9.jpg" />
      </figure>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: check link below to see preview
.
https://codepen.io/ilham-nopihendri/pen/OJEvBBo